# How to add text into span after document.createElement("span");?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to write text into an element span with function .text(), but I got this error
**UncaughtTypeError: undefined is not a function**, and I also tried function append(), innerHtml(), createTextNode() with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var closeSpan = document.createElement("span");
closeSpan.setAttribute("class","sr-only");
closeSpan.text("Close"); //UncaughtTypeError: undefined is not a function
```

OR

```
var closeSpan = document.createElement("span");
closeSpan.setAttribute("class","sr-only");
closeSpan.append("Close"); //UncaughtTypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: `.text()` is jQuery's function. Use `closeSpan.textContent = "Close";` Don't know what is DOM version of jQuery's `.append()`

Comment: `innerHTML` / `innerText` / `textContent` is a property, not a function (`span.innerHTML = 'Close'`). `createTextNode` only creates a text node, you still need to add it to the element (`span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Close'))`).

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* - You are mixing up jQuery and DOM methods. Can you explain why you call `document.createElement()` in the first place? (Also have a look at the [documentation for DOM Node objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), neither `.text()` nor `.append()` exist there.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since you are starting with pure DOM code, I'd suggest continuing with pure DOM code:

```
var closeSpan = document.createElement("span");
closeSpan.setAttribute("class","sr-only");
closeSpan.textContent = "Close";
```

In other words, just set [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) to the value you want.

If compatibility with IE 8 or earlier matters to you, note that `textContent` does not exist for those older browsers. For those older ones you'd have to use `innerText` (which works on IE 8 but is not part of any standard) or `innerHTML`. See the MDN page on `textContent` (which I link to above) for a discussion of the differences between these fields.

Answer (score 7):

If you **don't** want to use jquery, you would use `closeSpan.appendChild` and `document.createTextNode` like so:

```
var closeSpan = document.createElement("span");
closeSpan.setAttribute("class","sr-only");
closeSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Close"));
```

This method maximizes cross browser compatibility. It will work in all browsers, including old versions of IE.

If you **do** want to use jquery, you could do this in one line:

```
var closeSpan = $("<span></span>").addClass("sr-only").text("Close")[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to add the "span" tag to a div with id "myDiv":

```
var span = $("span"); // create element span
$(span).html("your text"); // add text
$("#myDiv").append($(span)); // append it to the div element
```

Comment: FYI there is no need to do `.append($(span))`. In your code, `span` *already is* a jQuery object, `.append(span)` will do just fine. Or `span.appendTo("#myDiv")`. That's also the reason why the correct naming convention for that variable would have been `$span`.

Comment: Doing `$("span")` does not create a span. It selects every existing span in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this also

```
var closeSpan = document.createElement("span");
closeSpan.setAttribute("class","sr-only");
closeSpan.html("Close");
```